# К самому собору

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

"Собор Парижской Богоматери":

> Будучи атакованы с фланга со стороны улицы Сен-Пьер-о-Бёф, а с тыла со стороны Папертной улицы, подавшись к **самому** Собору Богоматери, который они продолжали ещё осаждать, а Квазимодо — защищать, они оказались осаждающим и осаждёнными одновременно.

Я правильно понимаю, что *самому* тут от слова *самый,* а не от *сам,* и поэтому ударение в нём на первый слог?

Comment: Если кратко, то контекст позволяет принять оба толкования. Надо перечитывать всю картину боя, да и то - без гарантии, что что-то даст. Но навскидку - скорее именно к "самом**у**".  Там, как вспоминается, "сражение" происходило на площади перед Собором - а потом переместилось к к "самом**у**" Собору.

Comment: Спасибо, Бегемотус! Мне тоже так начало казаться после ваших слов.)) Однако я случайно пропустил кусочек текста, сейчас вставлю.